# Android: error occurs when taking a picture in landscape

Tags: android, camera, photo, landscape

I am trying to use the built-in camera application to take a photo and view it through an ImageView.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo);

    addButtonListeners();
    startCamera();
}

private void startCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_TAKEN);
}

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == PHOTO_TAKEN) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        if (photo != null) {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_background);
            image.setImageBitmap(photo);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.unable_to_read_photo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

When holding the phone in portrait position this code works just fine, however when I take the picture in landscape it breaks, any ideas why or how to solve this?

Comment: It breaks means what? what error you are getting in logcat console?

Comment: welcome to the "platform independent Java and Android" I bet your code works on the XXX th device and on the +1 doesn't. How many times to tell: Audio and video should be processed in native mode and is device dependent, regardless what says the documentation?!

Comment: Hi, what's breaking and how is it breaking? Paste some `LogCat` output please ..

Comment: try to add configurationchanges:keyboard in manifest file or just call a function on configuation changes method......

Answer (score 0):

Question in not defined with enough details to answer it for sure, but my guess would be the same as Shani Goriwal .

It looks like problems with configuration changes event - which happens each time orientation is changed (from  landscape to portrait).

Try to add to AndroidManifest of your app following lines:
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

(more details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found a tutorial that explains how to appropriately use the in built camera. Here is the [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/).

I am relativly new on android but from what I have read is the every time the display rotates android creates a new instance of some sort. So you have to save the instance of the rotation and this is done with the following code:

```
/**
* Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
* app
*/
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

// save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
// changes
outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
}

/*
* Here we restore the fileUri again
*/
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}
```

If you click on the link you should go to bullet number 11. *Avoiding NullPointerException after taking camera picture*. The real hero here is Ravi Tamada who does an excellent tutorial on using the camera. I recommend reading the whole tutorial.

Again I am new at this so if there is any corrections on what I have wrote here please correct.